# How to resolve Spring Cloud API Gateway is not working issue?

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have created two services (USER-SERVICE(8081) & DEPARTMENT-SERVICE(8080) along with service service (8761) registry and created API Gateway which runs on port 9191. All services are registered on service registry. Direct URL to each services are able to access.  But service via API Gateway is not working.

http://localhost:8081/api/users/3 --> Working
http://USER-SERVICE/api/users/3  --> IS NOT WORKING AND going to fallback error page.
http://localhost:9191/api/users/3 --> IS NOT WORKING AND going to fallback error page.

Using:
Java = 17,
Spring Cloud = 2023.0.0

[image: Service Registry Screenshot]

- **API Config:**

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER-SERVICE
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/users/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/departments/**
```

- **Department Service**

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
@RequestMapping("api/departments")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DepartmentController {

    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    private ReadConfig readConfig;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Department> saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department){
        Department savedDepartment = departmentService.saveDepartment(department);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedDepartment, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Department> getDepartmentById(@PathVariable("id") Long departmentId){
        Department department = departmentService.getDepartmentById(departmentId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(department);
    }

    @GetMapping("/checkconfigproperty")
    public ResponseEntity<ReadConfig> getConfigPropertyCheck(){
        System.out.println("readConfig.mypropertvalue =="+readConfig.getMypropertvalue());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(readConfig);
    }
}
```

**- **User Service ****

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/users")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
        User savedUser = userService.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
        ResponseDto responseDto = userService.getUser(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDto);
    }
}
```

API Gateway should to routed to User Service.

Comment: Please share your build configuration (pom/gradle) file